# How to write to a vector cyclically?

Tags: c++

I have a vector WITHOUT SIZE (infinite).

```
vector<int> myVector
```

I do push_back, but it inserts elements into the back endlessly.
I need only 5 elements to be written to the vector, and then they will be overwritten (starting from the old elements!).
How to do this in the easiest way?

I tried to write to the beginning and tried to do the rotation of the vector, but it did not work.

Comment: As for me then I have not understood what you are trying to do. Could you provide an example of the initial and result data in the vector?

Comment: Sounds like a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), you are looking for.

Comment: - or a queue...

Comment: Although, I rarely need it, I once asked myself why `std` doesn't provide a ring buffer. With [google "std ring buffer c++"](https://www.google.com/search?q=std+ring+buffer+c%2B%2B), I found [Chapter 8. Boost.Circular Buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/circular_buffer.html).

Comment: I want rewrite pushed element. If you could be able to move the "recorder" of push_back() to the beginning of the vector (without losing the all elements except the rewritable one) - this would solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

> need only 5 elements to be written to the vector, and then they will be overwritten

Then you don't want a vector. What you're describing is a circular buffer (also called cyclic or ring buffer).

The standard library does not have such container, but it can be implemented using either an array or a vector (depending on whether you want the size to be determined at compile or at runtime).

> How to do this in the easiest way?

The easiest way, as always, is to use an implementation written by somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write some wrapper on vector. A class where you will keep `vector<int>` for values and a `counter` to keep index where you want to insert or override element.

Also define some InsertValue public function to call it to insert or override elements in vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class CircularVector
{
public:
    CircularVector() : index(0)
    {
        m_vector.resize(5);
    }
    void InsertElement(int value)
    {
        m_vector[index%5] = value;

        index++;
    }
    std::vector<int>& getVector()
    {
        return m_vector;
    }
private:
    int index;
    std::vector<int> m_vector;
};
int main()
{
    CircularVector v;
    v.InsertElement(1);
    v.InsertElement(2);
    v.InsertElement(3);
    v.InsertElement(4);
    v.InsertElement(5);
    v.InsertElement(6);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << v.getVector()[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

output is `6 2 3 4 5`

Comment: Well, it is going to be a little bit pain, if I want use other functions of vector

Comment: @MiradilZeynalli If you could freely use other functions of vector, you could easily break assumption that the size doesn't change. The little pain is worth it for preventing that.

Comment: well, kinda makes sense)

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry. Have to use `resize()` not `reserve()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can write you own function for that. I would prefer to do it like this:

```
const int max_len = 5

vector<int> v(max_len);  // just get slots in memory for 5 elements

void insert_element(int n)
{
    static int index = 0;
    index %= v.size(); // do not let overflow

    v[index++] = n;
}

int main()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        insert_element(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < max_len; ++i)
        printf("%d ", v[i]); // output will be '5 6 7 8 9'
}
```

Comment: `#define MAX_SIZE 5` you should only use macros if it is really required. And that is not a situation when to use it.

Comment: you defined a max size on vector and never do a push_back. Isn't better std::array?

Comment: Well, he asked for vector, that is why, I gave my answer with vector. I also do believe that, this task can be done with arrays.

Comment: Making `v` freely accessible and  having `index = (index + 1) % max_len` and `v[index] = n` is error prone, and could result in out of bound access if the the vector length is modified.

Comment: Well, I do not understand the logic changing size of vector on mid-code, however, I still changed my answer to be error-free. Instead of taking mod from `max_len`, I do it from `v.size()`

Comment: I didn't say it makes sense to change the size of the vector, I just said that it is a bad design to write the code that way. It is slightly better now, but `v[index] = n;` can still be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost ready solution: [std::queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) which implements cyclic buffer.

```cpp
template<size_t limit, typename T>
bool push_with_limit(std::queue<T>& q, T&&x)
{
    bool value_dropped = false;
    while (q.size() >= limit) {
        q.pop_front();
        value_dropped = true;
    }
    q.push_back(std::forward<T>(x));

    return value_dropped;
}
```